# Using variables from one Python script in other Python scripts?

Tags: python

I want to set up a single python file containing variables that have the locations of all my data sources.  This would then be used by all my other scripts, then as a data source changes, I only have to edit the one file.

My Data_sources.py would look something like this:

```
BC_BEC = "Database Connections\\BC.sde\\FOREST_BC.BC_Eco\\BC.BC_BEC"
BC_TFL = "Database Connections\\Forest_BC.sde\\BC.BC_Admin\\BC.TFL_Boundary"
```

and so on...

How do I get all my other scripts to load or access these variables in the Data_sources.py?

Comment: Questions such as this, which are pure Python rather than about a Python module or site-package for GIS should normally be researched/asked at [so].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create an installed Python module that is importable from every Python script you run by using [Distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/introduction.html#a-simple-example) to package it.

From the Python doc:

> If all you want to do is distribute a
>   module called foo, contained in a file
>   foo.py, then your setup script can be
>   as simple as this:
>
> ```
> from distutils.core import setup
> setup(name='foo',
>       version='1.0',
>       py_modules=['foo'],
>       )
> ```

You can then install it via

```
python.exe setup.py install
```

And then you can import foo from any Python script, or you can use

```
python.exe setup.py bdist_wininst
```

To create a windows installer for the module so you can distribute it to other computers.

Comment: there's a nice chapter in the 'Byte of Python' book showing examples of building using ang importing modules.

Comment: I like this suggestion of creating a Module but I'm not very knowledgeable of them. The command "python.exe setup.py install" will use a pointer to foo.py, or will it use what's currently in foo.py?   If I later change foo.py the module will still be current?    Thanks.

Comment: I'll also look for that book.   Thanks for the help Jason and jonatr.

Comment: Vocabulary correction: the more precise python word is "package" -- helpful for looking up documentation, and to be clear that packages and modules are two different things in the python world. Also, a suggestion/hint: If you do `setup.py develop` (instead of `install`), edits to the package will be picked up as soon as they are saved, without need for a reinstall. (This is probably appropriate for the original questioner's data_sources.py.)

Comment: Isn't the user just asking how to import? Answer to that below.

Answer (score 12):

In any script in the same directory as Data_sources.py, put

```
from Data_sources import BC_BEC, BC_TFL
```

at the top. This works because the working directory is always at the head of the python path unless you've modified it.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path[0] == ''
True
```

See also: http://diveintopython.org/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html#d0e4550

If you want to share the data more widely, you can package it like others have suggested.

Answer (score 8):

Create a text config file and read it with Python's [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html).

Slightly nicer examples than the official documentation at http://effbot.org/librarybook/configparser.htm

Comment: @usererror - a package is good for distributing code, but it doesn't really solve the issue of keeping your parameters in one place.